# hash for derived class

Tags: c++, templates, subclassing

I'm having a case where I derive a class without changing any of its data, so preserving the hash function of its parent would be just fine. However, this doesn't happen out of the box:

```
#include <unordered_set>

struct A { size_t value; };
struct B : public A {};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<A>
    {
        typedef A argument_type;
        typedef size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& a) const noexcept { return a.value; }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<A> a_set; // works fine
    std::unordered_set<B> b_set; // error: hash<B> not found
}
```

Is there a simple way of making this work without explicitly implementing `hash<B>`?

Comment: Googling "std hash derived classes" turns up many hits, including on this site. Have you looked at them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
template <class T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, bool>::type = true // just for the hard error
> using hash = std::hash<A>;

std::unordered_set<A> a_set;
std::unordered_set<B, hash<B>> b_set;
```

or you just can pass `std::hash<A>` directly to `B` set as:

```
std::unordered_set<B, hash<A>> b_set;
```

Comment: I'm getting `error: redefinition of 'hash' as different kind of symbol`